# Simple C++ server-client application with winsock

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server, winsock

I'm trying to write a simple server-client application, which all it's supposed to do is this:
Client connects to server, Server waits for a message, client takes input from user, and sends it over to the server. Server receives this message, and sends it back to the client, client prints the message and loops and starts over again.
However, for some reason I have a rather weird problem: when I send my first message, server responds with it, when I send my second message, server responds again with the first message. When I send my third message, server responds with the second message and so forth.

Here's my server code that handles the connection:

```
class themusers {
    char ReMessage[200],SeMessage[200];

public:
    void * HandleConnections(SOCKET connector,int location) {

    std::string Converter;

        for (;;) {

        if (recv(connector,ReMessage,sizeof(ReMessage),NULL) == -1)
            std::cout << "Disconnected." << std::endl;
            discon.lock();
            sock_connection[location] = NULL;
            discon.unlock();
            break;
        }


        else {
                   //this is the code that handles the receive/send operation
            msgmut.lock();
            //std:: cout << ReMessage << std::endl;
            memcpy(SeMessage, ReMessage, sizeof(ReMessage));
            send(connector, SeMessage, sizeof(SeMessage), NULL);
            msgmut.unlock();        
        }

        }


        return NULL;
        }
};
```

And this is my client code:

```
for (;;) {
    cin >> tell;
    send(sock, tell, sizeof(tell), NULL);
    recv(sock,Message,sizeof(Message),NULL);
    Converter = Message;
    cout << "Server: " << Converter << endl;
}
```

Comment: Maybe a problem with 'cin' rather than sockets? Doesn't it do strange things with buffering input?

Comment: Aren't you missing a curly after the `if` in the server code?

Comment: Nope, just checked. Don't seem to.

Comment: Added a cout right after the cin, and it doesn't look like it's the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are missing a `{` in the `HandleConnections` function as posted here.

Comment: what type is `tell`?? If it's not *exactly* `char tell[200];` you'll have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb with [TCP] socket programming - **count your bytes**. That means actually paying attention to the values returned from `send(2)` and `recv(2)`. They tell you how much of your buffer was sent out and filled in from the network respectively.

The situation is a bit different with UDP, but that's probably not important here.

Comment: In particular, a `send` of 200 bytes could be `recv'd at the other end in several smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0):

The Boost ASIO is a really good C++ library for network and socket i/o usages for implementing both synchronous and asynchronous operations.

You can find it here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

They also have examples which illustrate implementing their libraries for a chat-server, and other uses as well:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

If you're interested in learning how to build asynchronous operations, you should look into the proactor design pattern.

Comment: all true, but overkill for this simple case

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nikolai. It important to record number of bytes returned. Also, changing default else clause to be conditional upon return value from recv().

Does your compiler define NULL as zero? It would probably be safer to change that arg in recv function to zero as well.

you might also consider modifying/zeroing your receive buffer after copying to send buffer. ( For trace-ability purposes )